# How to copy Mongo Database from Corrupted HDD

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

My current Hard Disk got currupted, I got mongodb /var/lib/mongodb folder , How can I dump and restore the mongodb database to new HDD,

I am using ubuntu, the mongodb folder contains, .ns and 0,1,2 database files.

Comment: There are two questions here and I think the first question "recover data from corrupted hdd" is a question for another stackoverflow domain.

Comment: You should also given some info on what things you have tried.

Comment: I got all files from the folder /var/lib/mongodb/ , it haves the database files, I tried to copy all the .ns files and supported 0,1 files to same mongodb folder in the new hdd , but I am having issue with starting the mongodb service